# Wrong Output in self defined Quaternionic Multiplication

Tags: function-construction, quaternions

I tried to define quaternionic multiplication in terms of pairs of complex numbers where I identify $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\mathbb{H}$ via $(z,w)\mapsto z+jw$. Consequently, I used the multiplication rule

```
Q /: Q[a_, b_]*Q[c_, d_] := 
 Q[a*c - Conjugate[b]*d, Conjugate[a]*d + b*c]
```

Strangely enough, the input

```
Q[0, 1]*Q[0, I]
```

Gives the incorrect output

```
Q[I, 0]
```

However, typing

```
Q[0, 1]*Q[a, I]
```

Gives the correct output

```
Q[-I, a]
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

Multiplication with `*` is commutative (technically, [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)), whereas quaternionic multiplication is not. Because `*` automatically puts its terms in normal order before multiplying, you sometimes end up with a commuted result. In your case this happens because `I` comes before `1` in the alphabet, and `0` comes before `a`, so the two terms are commuted (exchanged) automatically (try `Sort[{Q[0, 1], Q[0, I]}]` and `Sort[{Q[0, 1], Q[a, I]}]`).

The solution is to use [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) to prevent term reordering:

```
Q /: Q[a_, b_] ** Q[c_, d_] := Q[a*c - Conjugate[b]*d, Conjugate[a]*d + b*c]

Q[0, 1] ** Q[0, I]
(*    Q[-I, 0]    *)

Q[0, 1] ** Q[a, I]
(*    Q[-I, a]    *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!:)